# Spring JPA: primary key is a foreign key - This class does not define an IdClass

Tags: spring, jpa, primary-key

I'm creating an Entity with a primary key that is also a foreign key at the same time. However, I'm getting the following error "This class does not define an IdClass". What could be the problem?

### class Quote

```
@Entity
@Data
@IdClass(Instrument.class)
public class Quote implements Serializable  {

    @Id
    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "instrument")
    @NotNull
    private Instrument instrument;

    @NotNull
    private String time;

    @NotNull
    private double bid;

    @NotNull
    private double ask;

    @CreatedDate
    @Temporal(TIMESTAMP)
    @NotNull
    protected Date creationDate = new Date();

}
```

### class Instrument

```
@Entity
@Data
public class Instrument implements Serializable {

    @Id
    private String instrument;

    @NotNull
    private Currency currencyPrimary;

    @NotNull
    private Currency currencySecondary;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You missing constructor contain field take primary key @id.(instrumentId : It is my example)  and missing equal and hashCode in Instrument  class.

Comment: But I have @Data Lombok annotation that adds all the missing boilerplate code. Anyway, I will give it a try. Thanks.